# React.js Video tag src get request return "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am uploading video for my project there is no problem that. My problem is show the static file on public/uploads folder. It is working well on localhost but when I deploy on heroku I am getting this "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

[image: video file make a get request like this]

[image: or like this from another page]

result

[image]

and my react component looks like this

[image]

as i said it's working on my localhost. It happened in my get requests before from express api routers and i added package.json "localhost:5000" and homepage: "." things why still this is happen

Answer (score 0):

Your server isn't correctly configured, it is serving `index.html` (which contains "You need to enable JavaScript") for all requests.

Either your Heroku instance is serving `index.html` directly instead of passing it on to your Express server, or your Express server isn't correctly matching the `/uploads/` route.